# HTML make footer solid

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make a footer div solid? So that content in the main div stops scrolling behind it?

This is my footer code:

```css
Footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #515151;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 6.5%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="Footer">
  <span class="privacy"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></span>
  <span class="copyright"><p>Copyright</p></span>
</footer>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question more?

Comment: Can you not put the same amount of margin or padding on the bottom content div the same as the height of your footer? That will just mean the content never goes below the footer as only the padding or margin will

Comment: Try a `z-index`? It's a little to little information to really give a good answer at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

If you set position fixed. The element does not care about other content. You need to set in on relative.

```css
Footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #515151;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 6.5%;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer class="Footer">
  <span class="privacy"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></span>
  <span class="copyright"><p>Copyright</p></span>
</footer>
```

Comment: But when I change it to relative, it just goes to the content nearest to the bottom.  It also isn't the full width of the page.

Comment: Of course it isn't the full width of your page if you don't set the margin to 0 of  the body or html. I changed it on the snippet.

Comment: This still doesn't stick to the bottom, it still attaches to the nearest content

Comment: I know. But if you want a sticky footer the content will scroll "behind" it. SO what i think you want to have is a footer which is on the bottom if their is not enough content but if their is enough content it will stay after the last content?

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` instead of `position: fixed`

**Example:**

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #515151;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 6.5%;
}
```